# How to send a promise get request after a php json file has loaded?

Tags: javascript, php, json, forms

I'm trying to make an alert message to show if a username is taken after it is submitted from a post form to a php  file with json. I made this javascript file with a promise get request to get the json -

```
window.onload = function(){

    function get(url) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.open("GET", url);
          xhr.onload = () => resolve(xhr.responseText);
          xhr.onerror = () => reject(xhr.statusText);
          xhr.send();
        });
      }

    document.getElementById('register').addEventListener('submit', () => {
            let promise = get('/controllers/add-user.php').then((name) => {
            console.log(name);
        });
    });
}
```

My problem is that the promise is executing before the php file with json has loaded, and so I get these errors in my console

```
[Thu Aug 16 12:16:22 2018] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: password in /home/orpheus/Practice_dev/imagePoster/controllers/add-user.php on line 5
[Thu Aug 16 12:16:22 2018] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: app in /home/orpheus/Practice_dev/imagePoster/controllers/add-user.php on line 7
[Thu Aug 16 12:16:22 2018] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function nameTaken() on null in /home/orpheus/Practice_dev/imagePoster/controllers/add-user.php:7
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/orpheus/Practice_dev/imagePoster/controllers/add-user.php on line 7
[Thu Aug 16 12:16:22 2018] 127.0.0.1:44996 [500]: /controllers/add-user.php - Uncaught Error: Call to a member function nameTaken() on null in /home/orpheus/Practice_dev/imagePoster/controllers/add-user.php:7
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/orpheus/Practice_dev/imagePoster/controllers/add-user.php on line 7
```

The php file loads correctly and shows the correct json though. When I redirect back to the page with my promise, my console is cleared. So I want to know how do I make a promise get request to the json file after it is loaded and I am redirected back to my main page ('/')?

If I can't make a get request to my php post request, then how can I do what I want? My form post to my database and php file is already working, it submits names to my database if not used, and if already used it blocks them. I want to show in my html that the username is already used if it is taken though and I'm not sure if my method to do this is correct. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

> So I want to know how do I make a promise get request to the json file after it is loaded and I am redirected back to my main page ('/')?

You have to run the JavaScript that makes that request from your main page.

You can't do it from the previous page as you leave that page. The JS environment that XMLHttpRequest request is running from will be destroyed.